# Delphi IDE is not visible

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe3

I double click the `Delphi` icon on the `desktop`, but the `IDE` does not show up. Looking into the `Task Manager` list, the `BDS.exe` appears under the `Processes` list, while it should appear under the `Applications` list. Has anyone any idea why this is happening? Note: the `IDE` version I'm currently using is `XE3`, but the `2010` version, wich is also installed, behaves the same way. `Windows version is 8.1`. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Often this happens because you've got either a poorly behaving third-party component installed, or you've set the IDE to load the last project when it opens and it can't do that for some reason.

There are a few things that can help resolve this; they involve editing the shortcut to Delphi temporarily (or creating a new shortcut and modifying it instead, of course).

- Edit the shortcut and add the `-np` parameter to the command line; it tells the IDE to not load a project on startup. If this works, you can try opening your project. If the IDE hangs again, rename your `.dproj` file to a different extension and open it with just the `.dpr`; the IDE will create a new `.dproj` file;
- If the above doesn't work, edit the shortcut again, remove the `-np`, and replace it with `-rFoo`. This tells the IDE to load the `Foo` configuration from the registry on startup instead of the normal `Delphi` configuration. (`Foo` doesn't exist, so the IDE will create an all-new configuration in the registry named `Foo`, with no third-party components installed and all of the default settings for folders and options.) If this works, you can reinstall your third-party component sets one at a time to identify the problem package, and the edit the registry to remove it from your normal Delphi configuration.

Note: `Foo` in the second bullet point item above is just a name. It has no special meaning; it's just something that's commonly used as a dummy type or variable content. The parameter can be set to anything that doesn't already exist as a configuration in the Delphi registry settings; `Bar`, `Dummy` or `Zombie` will work just as well.

Once you've tried these (whether they fix the issue or not), don't forget to go back to remove the no longer needed command line parameter.

If none of the above works, a reinstall may be in order.

If you want to try a reinstall, uninstall the existing version (using the usual Control Panel **Uninstall Software** applet).

Doing an uninstall does not remove the registry keys, and a new install will see it exists and not create a new one, so you'll need to use RegEdit to delete the `HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\10.0` tree (or rename it to something different like `Old 10.0`), and then reinstall Delphi. (As you're using other Delphi versions, make sure you leave those keys alone so you don't damage those installs. Only alter or delete the `10.0` tree.)

Comment: Hi Ken. Thanks for your directions! I've tried both the `-np` and the `rFoo` but sadly neither resolved the issue. Before I read your answer, I uninstalled `Delphi` and reinstalled from scratch. Even so, it mantains this strange behavoir. Since I have not reinstalled any third party component, this must not be the problem. Also never have any project open with this recent installation. So what is really happenning? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Uninstalling Delphi does not remove the registry keys, so any third party components would still be there. The new installation would see the existing key and therefore not replace it. If you want to try a reinstall, uninstall the existing version, use RegEdit to delete the `HKCU\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\10.0` key (or rename it to something different like `Old 10.0`), and then reinstall Delphi. (As you're using other Delphi versions, make sure you leave those keys alone so you don't damage those installs.)

Comment: Thanks Ken. In fact, besides uninstalling `Delphi`, I've used `IOBIt Uninstaller`, that should have done a deep uninstallation, and alegedly should have cleaned up those keys. Nevertheless, I will check those keys, and in case they are there, I'll proceed as you directed me.

Comment: Hi Ken. I did as you said: changed `10.0` key to `10.0 old`. Delphi created a new `10.0` key but still is not opening the IDE. What else you think I can do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall did not help. Would you have any other suggestion?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. If it were me, I'd contact Embarcadero Support (http://support.embarcadero.com) and open up a free support ticket (which is available for installation-related issues). As that seems to be where you're at now, they can probably help you out; I'm sure they've encountered this issue before.

Comment: I can't see this .dproj extension you mention, only the .DPR file. Files not set to hidden so am I missing something? Using Delphi 7.

Comment: @Chucky: I think the .dproj files might have started with D2005, so they may not apply to Delphi 7; I don't have it installed right now to check, I'm afraid.

Comment: I just read "Delphi 2007 and newer" from here http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Delphi_File_Extensions. Drat.

Comment: I have same issue. First i had XE2 and 10.1 installed. Both worked fine. Then I installed 10.2. All 3 worked fine. I did not try any in a while, then I noticed only 10.2 starts. I did not install any components and now all 3 fail to start (bds.exe process just closes). Command line switches didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 4 and 5 it was the delphi32.dsk file. You can delete this file but you can also edit the file, section 'Main Window'. First kill the process in the taskmanager before you edit/delete this disk file.

```
[Main Window]
Create=1
Visible=0   <-- This value must be **1**
State=0
......
......
```

Start Delphi - et viola! It is back again.

Offtopic: Still running Delphi 5 on Windows 7, blazing fast, yes!